# How to read a 3rd string in a file by makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to convert some cmd script to a makefile with no success.
The script is:

```
for /F "eol=* tokens=2,3*" %%i in (%VERSION_FILE_PATH%\VersionInfo.h,%VERSION_FILE_PATH%\Version.h) do (

    if %%i==%MAJOR% set MAJOR_VALUE=%%j
    if %%i==%MINOR% set MINOR_VALUE=%%j
    if %%i==%HOTFIX% set HOTFIX_VALUE=%%j
    if %%i==%BUILD% set BUILD_VALUE=%%j
)
```

What the script does is searching for specific string in each line and gets the string followed.

for example: `#define MAJOR 4`
I'm searching for MAJOR and getting the 4.

My question is how to do it in makefile.

Comment: Make is build automation software; it isn't targeted to process any form of files. You can, however, launch any external program (including your cmd script) from makefile.

Answer (score 1):

If these lines always have the same structure, you could do it this way with awk:

```
tester: 
    cat test | grep MAJOR | awk '{print $$3}'
```

Where I made a little test file that just contains

```
#define MAJOR 4
```

You could loop over each line, grepping for the token you want, and then grabbing the third value with awk. Note that you need the double `$` to escape string expansion by `make`.